# Conditional clause to DROP Table

Tags: sql

I was trying to write a sql procedure to drop table who have a certain pattern in their names.
Something like the below code :

```
DECLARE @temp TABLE 
(
  ID bigint IDENTITY(1,1),
  tabname sysname NOT NULL
)
INSERT INTO @temp
SELECT TABLE_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_NAME LIKE '%:%'

DECLARE @ProcessedID bigint = 0
DECLARE @tablename sysname
SELECT @ProcessedID = ID, @tablename = tabname FROM @temp WHERE ID > @ProcessedID ORDER BY ID DESC
WHILE(@ProcessedID IS NOT NULL)
BEGIN
    DROP TABLE dbo.[@tablename]
    SELECT @ProcessedID = ID, @tablename = tabname FROM @temp WHERE ID > @ProcessedID ORDER BY ID DESC
END
```

But @tablename is not replaced with the right table name. Can any one point me in the right direction.

Comment: Your current code will go into an endless loop due to the fact that @ProcessedID will never be NULL

Comment: Yes, this is more of a psuedo code for better explanation of the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do it dynamically when you want to use a variable name as an argument, so you need to wrap it in a string and execute that string and then do some small changes to the WHILE condition to fit.

I'd properly do something like this:

```
DECLARE @temp TABLE 
(
  ID bigint IDENTITY(1,1),
  tabname sysname NOT NULL
):
INSERT INTO @temp
SELECT TABLE_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_NAME LIKE '%:%';

DECLARE @tablename VARCHAR(255);
DECLARE @Count INT = ISNULL((SELECT COUNT(*) FROM @temp AS t), 0);

WHILE(@Count > 0)
BEGIN

    SELECT @tablename = tabname FROM @temp AS t; --if the order of drop is not significant

    EXEC('DROP TABLE dbo.[' + @tablename+ ']'); 
    DELETE FROM @temp WHERE tabname = @tablename;
    SET @Count =  ISNULL((SELECT COUNT(*) FROM @temp AS t), 0);
END
```